# Ford explorer idle problem

Tags: ford, idle, explorer

My 96 explorer will idle about 400 at a stop sign and 1000 at the next stop sign what would cause this

Comment: Does this happen immediately after starting the car, or have you been driving for a while? Is the AC or heater running?

Comment: It just started happening about a week ago it use to idle high when started then go down to 700ish when warm now on start it will idle at 400 or 1000 and keeps changing back and forth I think it's also doing when I drive because I will be holding the gas steady and will start to go slower so I give it gas then all the sudden I'm picking up speed

Comment: This could be cause by a small vacuum leak or by a dirty air filter or mass airflow sensor (MAF). I'd start by checking/cleaning/replacing the intake air filter, then cleaning the MAF with electronic safe cleaner (can be found at auto parts stores).

Comment: Is there a check engine light? Have you had the codes read?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed mine by restricting air flow at the idle air valve. But rubber bushing inside hose. The hole in bushing is size of a small straw. No more high idle. Gas mileage was 18 hwy now 21 hwy.   John